# Running Quart in production behind Hypercorn

Tags: quart, hypercorn

Hey guys I am trying to run Quart in production.

That is my code:
**setups.py**

```
import quart.flask_patch
from db import *

from http import HTTPStatus
from typing import Optional


import flask.json
from quart import ResponseReturnValue, jsonify, Quart
from quart.ctx import RequestContext
from quart.exceptions import HTTPException
from quart_openapi import Pint

from .confs import __author__, __description__, __mail__, __title__, __version__,SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from .routes import initialize_routes
from .user_verify import get_jwks, verify_jwt
        

class PintCustom(Pint):
    def __init__(self, *args, no_openapi: bool = False, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.jwks = get_jwks()
        super().__init__(*args, no_openapi=no_openapi, **kwargs)

    async def preprocess_request(self, request_context: Optional[RequestContext] = None) -> Optional[
        ResponseReturnValue]:
        token = request_context.request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if request_context.request.method != 'OPTIONS':
            try:
                verify_jwt(str(token), self.jwks)
            except Exception:
                raise HTTPException(HTTPStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 403, 'Log in')

        return await super().preprocess_request(request_context)


def get_app_instance():
    # Initial app.
    # app = Quart(__name__)
    app = PintCustom(__name__, title=__title__, version=__version__, description=__description__,
                     contact_email=__mail__, contact=__author__)


    @app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
    def http_exception(e):
        return jsonify(error=e.name, error_details=e.description), e.status_code

    app.jwks = get_jwks()

    # Initial all the REST API routes.
    initialize_routes(app)


    # DB
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

**server.py**

```
__package__ = 'nini'

from .setups import create_app
from .db import db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    db.init_app(app)

    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

When I run  `hypercorn server:app`
I get :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nini'

I run the commend under ../nini/server.py

I don't see many tutorials on this.
Also tried to run:

> pipenv install quart
> pipenv shell
> export QUART_APP=server:app
> quart run

Same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app` instance on the `server` module only exists when you invoke that module as the main module, which Hypercorn does not do. Instead you can invoke the factory function, `hypercorn "server:create_app()"`.

You will likely want to move the `db.init_app(app)` line to within the `create_app` function (which I think you've called `get_app_instance`?) as it is also only called if you invoke server as the main module.

I don't think you need `__package__ = 'nini'`, which may also cause an issue.